# Adding background color to all pages using iTextSharp C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am creating PDF using iTextSharp C#. I have fixed header footer content that are bind with PDFEvents. I want to add background color to middle content in every page.

Here is my code

```
private void CreatePDF()
{
    string fileName = string.Empty;

    DateTime fileCreationDatetime = DateTime.Now;

    fileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf", fileCreationDatetime.ToString(@"yyyyMMdd") + "_" + fileCreationDatetime.ToString(@"HHmmss"));

    string pdfPath = Server.MapPath(@"~\PDF\") +   fileName;

    using (FileStream msReport = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        //step 1
        using (Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 140f, 10f))
        {
            try
            {
                // step 2
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, msReport);
                pdfWriter.PageEvent = new Common.ITextEvents();

                //open the stream 
                pdfDoc.Open();

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Hello world. Checking Header Footer", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 22));

                    para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                    pdfDoc.Add(para);

                    pdfDoc.NewPage();
                }

                pdfDoc.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle exception
            }

            finally
            {


            }

        }

    }
}
```

Here is my ITextEvents class that extends PdfPageEventHelper to add header/footer.

```
public class ITextEvents : PdfPageEventHelper
    {

        // This is the contentbyte object of the writer
        PdfContentByte cb;

        // we will put the final number of pages in a template
        PdfTemplate headerTemplate, footerTemplate;

        // this is the BaseFont we are going to use for the header / footer
        BaseFont bf = null;

        // This keeps track of the creation time
        DateTime PrintTime = DateTime.Now;


        #region Fields
        private string _header;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public string Header
        {
            get { return _header; }
            set { _header = value; }
        }
        #endregion


        public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            try
            {
                PrintTime = DateTime.Now;
                bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                cb = writer.DirectContent;
                headerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(100, 100);
                footerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                //handle exception here
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioe)
            {
                //handle exception here
            }
        }

        public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
        {
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

            iTextSharp.text.Font baseFontNormal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);

            iTextSharp.text.Font baseFontBig = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);

            Phrase p1Header = new Phrase("Sample Header Here", baseFontNormal);

            //Create PdfTable object
            PdfPTable pdfTab = new PdfPTable(3);

            //We will have to create separate cells to include image logo and 2 separate strings
            //Row 1
            PdfPCell pdfCell1 = new PdfPCell();
            PdfPCell pdfCell2 = new PdfPCell(p1Header);
            PdfPCell pdfCell3 = new PdfPCell();
            String text = "Page " + writer.PageNumber + " of ";


            //Add paging to header
            {
                cb.BeginText();
                cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(document.PageSize.GetRight(200), document.PageSize.GetTop(45));
                cb.ShowText(text);
                cb.EndText();
                float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 12);
                //Adds "12" in Page 1 of 12
                cb.AddTemplate(headerTemplate, document.PageSize.GetRight(200) + len, document.PageSize.GetTop(45));
            }
            //Add paging to footer
            {
                cb.BeginText();
                cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(document.PageSize.GetRight(180), document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
                cb.ShowText(text);
                cb.EndText();
                float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 12);
                cb.AddTemplate(footerTemplate, document.PageSize.GetRight(180) + len, document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
            }
            //Row 2
            PdfPCell pdfCell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sub Header Description", baseFontNormal));
            //Row 3


            PdfPCell pdfCell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date:" + PrintTime.ToShortDateString(), baseFontBig));
            PdfPCell pdfCell6 = new PdfPCell();
            PdfPCell pdfCell7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TIME:" + string.Format("{0:t}", DateTime.Now), baseFontBig));


            //set the alignment of all three cells and set border to 0
            pdfCell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pdfCell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pdfCell3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pdfCell4.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pdfCell5.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pdfCell6.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            pdfCell7.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;


            pdfCell2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
            pdfCell3.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            pdfCell4.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
            pdfCell5.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            pdfCell6.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            pdfCell7.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;


            pdfCell4.Colspan = 3;



            pdfCell1.Border = 0;
            pdfCell2.Border = 0;
            pdfCell3.Border = 0;
            pdfCell4.Border = 0;
            pdfCell5.Border = 0;
            pdfCell6.Border = 0;
            pdfCell7.Border = 0;


            //add all three cells into PdfTable
            pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell1);
            pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell2);
            pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell3);
            pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell4);
            pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell5);
            pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell6);
            pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell7);

            pdfTab.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 80f;
            pdfTab.WidthPercentage = 70;



            //call WriteSelectedRows of PdfTable. This writes rows from PdfWriter in PdfTable
            //first param is start row. -1 indicates there is no end row and all the rows to be included to write
            //Third and fourth param is x and y position to start writing
            pdfTab.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 40, document.PageSize.Height - 30, writer.DirectContent);

            //Move the pointer and draw line to separate header section from rest of page
            cb.MoveTo(40, document.PageSize.Height - 100);
            cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width - 40, document.PageSize.Height - 100);
            cb.Stroke();

            //Move the pointer and draw line to separate footer section from rest of page
            cb.MoveTo(40, document.PageSize.GetBottom(50));
            cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width - 40, document.PageSize.GetBottom(50));
            cb.Stroke();
        }

        public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

            headerTemplate.BeginText();
            headerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
            headerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
            headerTemplate.ShowText((writer.PageNumber - 1).ToString());
            headerTemplate.EndText();

            footerTemplate.BeginText();
            footerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
            footerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
            footerTemplate.ShowText((writer.PageNumber - 1).ToString());
            footerTemplate.EndText();


        }
    }
```

This is the code which I add to create background

```
cb.RoundRectangle(0f, 40f, document.PageSize.Width, document.PageSize.Height - 140f, 1f);
cb.SetColorFill(new CMYKColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.0706f));
cb.Fill();
```

This work fine on first page when I add this code in OpenDocument event. 2nd and further pages content are hidden behind this rectangle. Same goes with StartPage event.

Need help what I am doing wrong

Comment: well, you fill the `DirectContent` page area with colour when everything else has already been added. What else should happen than a covering of the already added content?

Comment: Yes that is the issue rectangle appearing on top of content in page 2 and further. Where do I need to put this code to add background color before adding content.

Comment: use the `UnderContent` instead of the `DirectContent`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by mkl comment I solved the issue by overriding **OnStartPage** function and usgin **DirectContentUnder** for adding background.

```
public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
  {
    base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
    var cbb = writer.DirectContentUnder;
    cbb.RoundRectangle(0f, 40f, document.PageSize.Width, document.PageSize.Height - 140f, 1f);
    cbb.SetColorFill(new CMYKColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.0706f));
    cbb.Fill();
  }
```

Comment: Strictly speaking I wouldn't use `OnStartPage` for this but `OnEndPage`. The use of `DirectContentUnder` instead of `DirectContent` is the trick.

Comment: Ok will use it inside OnEndPage.